# Refresh div content or open new content in div

Tags: php, jquery

I currently use this to to open new content in a div (so I don't have to refresh the whole page):

**file1.php**

```
<?php
//db connection

if ($res = $mysqli->query("SELECT field FROM table")) {

    /* determine number of rows result set */
    $row = $res->num_rows;

    echo "$row";

    $res->close();
}
?>
```

**jquery.js**

```
$.ajax({ 
  url: "file1.php", 
//this will run as soon as the php script echos the answer 
  success: function(result){  
$('#div1').html(result); 
} 
});
```

**page1.php**

```
<div id="div1">
</div>
```

**Code Updated**

Comment: That depends on what $result is. You could do an ajax call to get just the value of that variable, but it's hard to reccomend anything when there's no code or real explanation of what the point is.

Comment: @adeneo the result is my DB's row count. A number. What code should I add?

Comment: Is it part of a big div you want to refresh or you just want to refresh that single line in the div?

Comment: @ftom2 That single line. That's why I didn't post anything else. That is the only thing inside my div.

Comment: why not make an ajax call to the script that returns that count?

Comment: @ftom2 I am not much into ajax that's why I am asking if there is a way with .load to call that line again. If the way is only ajax I will see how to solve it...

Comment: @ftom2 I could just put that echo in an another file and just call that. But is that a good solution?

Comment: `load()` IS ajax, it's just a shortcut for `$.get`, which is just a shortcut for `$.ajax`. Create a simple PHP script that only returns the value you want, and use ajax to call that script and insert the returned values where you want them. Without any more code it's impossible to be more specific on how exactly you should do this ?

Comment: @adeneo you are saying what I said 2 comments above. But is this a "real" solution? What more code do you need? I can provide.

Comment: @ftom2 I have updated my code. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've edited my answer, the ajax doesn't automatically being called, you'll need to add some click event that will trigger it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comments i understand you are a bit confused, so i'll do my best to explain:

1. $.load is ajax wrapped in a more convenient method, so you are already using ajax without knowing it.
2. From what i understand, you get the result variable from DB, it is not just a static number in some page, so what you need is to make an ajax call to the script that fetches this result from DB and return it to the callback function:

**somePage.php:**

```
$result = ...//get data from DB
echo $result;
```

**jquery:**

```
$('#someBtn').click(function(){
$.ajax({
      url: "somePage.php",
    //this will run as soon as the php script echos the answer
      success: function(result){ 
    $('#content').html(result);
    }
    });
});
```

Of course you'll need a button in your HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="someBtn"/>
```

this is roughly how you do it. I suggest you take a look at [jquery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), it is not that hard.

Comment: 1. Yes I thought that what I was using was just called jquery. And 2. Yes my result is from a DB and is not just a static number. I am voting up for the explanation and I will check if the solution works. I alredy have my somePage.php so in few minutes I will get back to you.

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong, please update your question with the new code

Comment: ahhh... the "triger" to send the echo... Sorry... Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo "."$result."" ?>
```

syntax should be

```
<?php echo $result; ?>
```

@question

What you have stumbled on is Ajax. You will need to learn how to make simple ajax calls to refresh div contents after page load.

Comment: It is working for me like this `"" . $resQ['Qid'] . ""` but this is not my problem right now.

Comment: What else to post? What I have is working but I need to refresh it. As I said above the $result is my DB's row count. A number.

Comment: So you are saying that what I need is not possible with .load function?